# TFS not properly showing Line Break in Markdown table

Tags: tfs, markdown

I have a markdown file hosted on TFS with a table.  I'd like to have a multi-line cell in the table so I add `<br>` within the text of the table cell.

Locally (using Sublime Markdown Preview or even Visual Studio Web Extensions) things look correct.  However, once the file is checked-in and then displayed in the browser, the `<br>`'s are just displayed as-is in the table (i.e., no line break).  `<br>`'s in other places in the document are the same.

I've tried other solutions (2 spaces at the end of each line in the cell, using `<br />`) and nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Edit: It seems that *any* raw html that I put in my markdown document is just escaped (and therefore shown as raw text) in my document online.  Frustrating.

Comment: What did you mean displayed in the browser? Did you just mean open the file in tfs web portal? Moreover is this phenomenon only occurs with the specific markdown file or all are the same？

Comment: Yes, when opening the md file in the tfs web portal.  I'm not sure we've attempted to use <br>s in our other md files (yet) but I have no reason to believe that anything is special about the one that is having issues.

Comment: Hi Jeff, figured out if finally. When you're exporting to **HTML**, using `<br>` works. 

However, if you're using **pandoc** to export to LaTeX/PDF as well, you may have to use [grid tables](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables) as a workaround

Comment: Hi Jeff, did you figure out how to have line breaks in MD file e.g. in the code section? Everything what is marked as a code is in one long line (in preview it works, after save it doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

When you're exporting to **HTML**, using `<br>` works.

However, if you're using **pandoc** to export to LaTeX/PDF as well, you may have to use [grid tables](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables) as a workaround:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Header        | Header         | Header            |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Cell1         | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Cell2         | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

**In TFS widget：**

[image]

Moreover, here is  a nice package for Sublime Text: [Table Editor](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Table%20Editor)